# What is the SObject for a chat conversation?

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking, chatter-file

I want to monitor chat conversation and want to check and store at admin side. so admin can see who doing chat to whom and archive the conversation

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you're referring to the Chatter Messenger feature (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_chat_using.htm&language=en_US), the chat messages are not supported in the SObject API, or any other API.

Answer (score 4):

Don't expect this any time soon. Chatter Messenger will be unsupported in Spring '17, and is not available in new orgs created after Spring '16.

[Chatter Messenger: Retiring in Spring ’17](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_chatter_messenger_eol.htm)